# How to find residue of the following function.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Wolfram Alpha tells me that the residue of

$$ \frac {1}{e^z-1} $$ at the point z= $ 2i\pi $ is 1.

Now i understand how the formula for residue works for simple poles , i just don't understand how  $ (z-2i\pi) $ can cancel anything at the bottom. Basically i dont know how to prove this.

Could someone please help?

Thank you very much for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

Note that\begin{align}\lim_{z\to2\pi i}\frac{e^z-1}{z-2\pi i}&=\lim_{z\to2\pi i}\frac{e^z-e^{2\pi i}}{z-2\pi i}\\&=\exp'(2\pi i)\\&=e^{2\pi i}\\&=1.\end{align}Therefore,$$\lim_{z\to2\pi i}\frac{z-2\pi i}{e^z-1}=1$$and this is enough to prove that $\operatorname{res}_{z=2\pi i}\frac1{e^z-1}=1$.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [L'Hopital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule). Since both the numerator and denominator of your limit approach zero as $z\to 2\pi i$,

$$\lim_{z\to {2\pi i}} \frac{z-2\pi i}{e^z-1}=\lim_{z\to 2\pi i} \frac{1}{e^z}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac {1}{e^z-1} =\frac {1}{z+z^2/2 + z^3/6+...   } = 1/z -1/2+z/12+...$$

The residue is the coefficient of $1/z$ thus it is $1$